# Webservices Request and Response

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to consume a thirdparty webservice which expects a SOAP request but responds with a naked XML response - ie no SOAP envelope.

I've not come across this before. Is this a common thing to do?

Comment: Generally, it is not. Then again, does it really matter? As in, how does it change your approach? Note: using pre generated classes from WSDL is not necessarily the best idea in 2016.

Comment: As far as I can see it means that I can't use out of the box code in VisualStudio - which means vastly more work. They have supplied a WSDL but I'm guessing that the WSDL doesn't describe what is actually happening so .NET throws and error when it doesn't get a SOAP response. Why is using pre generated classes from a WSDL a bad idea?

Comment: Because ultimately when asked 'what is happening in your code' you will only be able to say 'i am calling some library'. WSDL code generation is not bad by itself; using it without understanding how it works and what the resulting code really does is.

Comment: As long as the response format is predictable it is not so difficult to consume xml. You can make your own data contract and deserialize it or read it into `XDocument` and use linq to xml.